# How do i cover the rail of an Ajax Slider Extender when i move the handle from step 0 to step 50 and have those steps colored gray?

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajax Slider Extender on my textbox, I am using a style sheet to change the rail to color green, that's going fine and dandy. Here is my code for the slider...

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="SliderID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="SliderID" 
        BehaviorID="BoundControl" 
        Minimum="0" 
        Maximum="100" 
        RailCssClass="SliderRail" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        EnableHandleAnimation="true" 
        Steps="100">
    </asp:SliderExtender>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS so far...

```
.SliderRail {
position: relative;
height: 18px;
width: 100%; 
background-color:green;
```

}

I know how to add an image to the handle, but what I am trying to figure out is how when I move the handle from step 0 to step 50, I need to mask over those steps with a dark grey and I can't really figure it out.

I have tried adding an image to the handle and have tried setting the width to a 100%, but that didn't work out at all for me.

My end result is figuring this problem out, then trying to replicate this using a multi handle extender when I have both handles at either end, it would do the same as the left handle, just backwards. Then I'll need to make sure that the handles can run over eachother...But that is the end result that I need to do. 
I don't want to use JQuery or JavaScript, just want to keep it strictly css. 
There isn't much documentation on using multi handles.

If this question has been asked a million times then I apologize, I must have been using the wrong search terms because I haven't found anything to tell me how to do this.

Thanks for all and any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dotnetslackers.com/Ajax/re-70082_SliderExtender_layout_and_custom_appearance.aspx

Custom Appearance
In order to customize the slider’s appearance, we need to:

Provide a CSS class for the rail
Provide a CSS class for the handle
Provide an image URL for the handle’s image.
Steps to perform:

1. Create a CSS class for the slider’s rail. The CSS class must contain the following attributes:

The position attribute must be set to relative.
Default values for height and width attributes must be provided. The width value can be overridden through the Length property of the SliderExtender.
To embed a background image for the rail, use the background attribute.
2. Create a CSS class for the slider’s handle. The CSS class must contain the following attributes:

The position attribute must be set to absolute.
Values for height and width attributes must be provided.
3. Provide an image for the slider’s handle. The height and width sizes of the image must be equal to the height and width values specified in the handle’s CSS class.

4. Set the RailCssClass property of the SliderExtender instance to the name of the rail CSS class.
5. Set the HandleCssClass property of the SliderExtender instance to the name of the handle CSS class.
6. Set the HandleImageUrl property of the SliderExtender instance to the URL of the handle’s image.